# What font has this distinctive "A" with a two-tone cross-bar?

Tags: font-identification

A few different sources have been using a sans-serif font with a distinctive cap "A"
with a two-tone cross-bar that looks like this screen shot:

[image: Cap "A" with two-tone cross bar]

Another character from the same font is the lc "y":

[image: ![lc "y"]

Edit: While researching TF vs microSD cards, I visited [the easeus 'computer instruction' website](https://www.easeus.com/computer-instruction/tf-card-vs-sd-card.html) and noticed the subheadings had the same two-tone cross-bar 'A' character. I found the same with both Safari and Firefox.

[image: Text sub-head on easeus.com site]

Comment: It's almost impossible to identify a font from two glyphs only. Find a longer example with more letters.  Also looks like there's something wrong with the font. The crossbar of an A should not have overlaps like this.

Comment: @BillyKerr, Yes, I agree with you on all counts. This really grabbed my attention, though. After looking around with no results, I thought I'd try StackExchange. Note that this is my first question after being here over ten years answering others. Please see edit with addition.

Comment: looks, like the linked website in the question uses Lexend font. It really is a variable font. It's said to be developed to help people who have reading difficulties. An already written answer (by Copilot) says that some web browsers may interpret overlapping paths wrong and overlapping is used in variable fonts. A web page programmer maybe could understand the page code, tell how the font is used and is it really a variable version of Lexend.

Answer (score 4):

Although it might be a font with this effect, I suspect that's a font rendering error caused by the program not reading overlapping elements of the glyph properly. Font families designed in multiple weights often have parts of the glyph designed separately and overlapping so they can expand separately in bolder weights, look at the top right 'ear' of this g.
[image: image of a g showing that the font is made of different parts]

If you can find the source tell me and can look at it.
(Edit: another contributor has done this and it is the program displaying the font misreading the overlap. Variable fonts often have these kinds of overlaps but it turns out the font served wasn't a variable font.)

Comment: In an edit to my question, I added a link to a website where the character appeared most recently. I also first saw it in an email graphic sent to me which I cannot now locate.

Answer (score 4):

You can inspect the web page to find the font. It's Lexend Semi-Bold.

Also after looking at the link, the letter A does not look like what you show. On my Windows 11 PC, using Firefox, it looks like a normal A. So there must be a rendering problem with your system/browser. The A is certainly not supposed to look like that.  Perhaps try using another browser.

Here's my screenshot (Firefox), showing the inspected Element

[image]Click to view larger